# Trouble implementing nested tabs using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, tabs

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9, jQuery 1.6.2 and jQuery UI. I am trying to implement nested tabs by following as well as possible the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs), but I get some "strange" behavior for those nested tabs when I use AJAX.

I have two tabs (`tab1` and `tab2`) each having two nested tabs (`tab1_sub1` and `tab1_sub2` nested\related to `tab1`, `tab2_sub1` and `tab2_sub2` nested\related to `tab2`).

After loading the page containing the mentioned tabs, the output HTML code is:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
          <a href="#tabs-1">
            tab1 title
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
          <a href="#ui-tabs-1">
            tab2 title
          </a>
        </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    <div id="tabs_sub1" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
          <a href="#tabs_sub1-1">
            tab1_sub1 title
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
          <a href="#ui-tabs-2">
            tab1_sub2 title
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div id="tabs_sub1-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
        tab1 content
      </div>

      <div id="ui-tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="ui-tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div>
</div>
```

At this time, on displaying the `tab1` content, `tab1_sub1` and `tab1_sub2` work, as well.

Now, clicking on the `tab2` title the output HTML code becomes:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
          <a href="#tabs-1">
            tab1 title
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
          <a href="#ui-tabs-1">
            tab2 title
          </a>
        </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
    <div id="tabs_sub1" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
          <a href="#tabs_sub1-1">
            tab1_sub1 title
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
          <a href="#ui-tabs-2">
            tab1_sub2 title
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div id="tabs_sub1-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
        tab2 content
      </div><div id="ui-tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="ui-tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">

    <div id="tabs_sub1" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
              <a href="#tabs_sub1-1">
                tab2_sub1 title
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
              <a href="http://<hostname>/<path>"> # I think here is the problem (read above for more information).
                tab2_sub2 title
              </a>
            </li>
      </ul>

      <div id="tabs_sub1-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Now, on displaying the `tab2` content, when I click on the `tab2_sub2` title it will load the `tab2_sub2` content on the top of the current page and not inside the `tab2_sub2` tab.* That is, the browser will go to the URL `http://<hostname>/<path>`.

The problem (I think) is exactly in the following code:

```
...
  <a href="http://<hostname>/<path>">
...
```

Maybe the `href` value should be something like `#ui-tabs-2` (as for\in the `tab1` content) and maybe there are some jQuery UI bugs when you use nested tabs in this way...

**How can I solve that?**

---

I have tried to solve the problem following [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Ajax_mode) and [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...open_links_in_the_current_tab_instead_of_leaving_the_page), but I didn't solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in `tabs` CSS id values. Those must be different for each `div` `id` HTML attribute related to the `<div id="tabs" class="...">`.

A simplest solution is to set `tabs1` and `tabs2` id values for those `div`s.